# Sending friend invites from a Facebook Connected site using new Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, request, invite

I'm developing a standalone website application that makes use of Facebook Connect and the new Javascript SDK that was released in June.

I've been trying to get friend invites working. I'm able to send an invite using a request dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), but the URL that the user clicks through to when they accept the invite is the internal Facebook app page (http://apps.facebook.com/APP_ID/?request_ids=REQUEST_ID&ref=notif), not my site URL.

Is there any way to fix this so invites work with FB Connected web applications?

It seems this was possible with previous versions of the SDK.

I have seen some posts recommending a redirect from the canvas page, but I have also read that this can lead to the application being suspended by Facebook: 
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=343257#p343257

Many thanks for assistance on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would never expect Facebook to lead me to an external URL by accepting an invite via the request system - especially when most invites/requests tend to be spam.

Have you thought of distributing your invites via the Facebook Message system or sending them via email instead?

This would make the whole process a lot less misleading to a user.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I see your point but find it strange that you're able to send invites from a facebook-connected website via the JS SDK but not actually lead the recipient back to the site that the invite was sent from. I would gladly take a look at the message system but I don't believe there's an SDK that allows you to send messages is there? To clarify what I'm trying to achieve - in the application a user can build a quiz. When they have done so I would like them to be able to invite their friends to play it in the same way they can do with the facebook app version. Thanks.

Comment: @user636679 I suppose that you could either do that or just post the link to a person's wall?

Comment: Yes I think that's the best thing to do, rather than trying to fiddle the invites. I don't think it's possible to send messages via the messaging system programatically.

Comment: @user636679 Yes, using the graph it's not possible, but you can request the permission of the user's email by requesting the `email` permission - but the user would already have to be using your site before you send the request - scrap that idea lol

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer - if not just based on this conversation. :)